# How to write MySql query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin

How can I write query for below table in Laravel.
Like In my app logged user id is 109
So I need whose user match with logged user in BlindDate and PaidDate table to user id.

[This is User table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVUxt.png)

[This is BlindDate table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umKge.png)

[THis is PaidDate table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvMlr.png)

I want need expected output is :

```
data[
  
  'blind_users':[
     {
        'uuid':'rvfv',
        'user_id':109,
        'touser':[
            {
              'name':'james',
              'email':'xxxx@gmail.com'
            }  
         ]

     },
     {
        'uuid':'rvfv',
        'user_id':109,
        'touser':[
            {
              'name':'james',
              'email':'xxxx@gmail.com'
            }  
         ]

     },
  ],

 'paid_date_users':[
   {
        'uuid':'rvfv',
        'user_id':109,
        'touser':[
            {
              'name':'james',
              'email':'xxxx@gmail.com'
            }  
         ]

     },
  ]

]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully you have setup the eloquent Model and its relations since you are using Laravel for this project!

If you only have the user id you can query the User model like so

```
return User::with('blind_date', 'paid_date')->where('id', $userId)->first();
```

If you have an authenticated user you can just return the user without any eager loading or just call it in you blade like `auth()->user()`

Comment: Ho can I attach to_user_id data from user table?

Answer (score -1):

Ans: Use these two function  in  user model.

```
public function bind_dates(){
  return $this->belongsTo('binddates','user_id');
}
    
public function free_paid_dates(){
  return $this->belongsTo('freepaiddates','user_id');
}
```

Query:

```
Users::with('free_paid_dates','bind_dates')->where('id',$user_id)->get();
```

If you have a multiple user, user `hasMany` relation.

Please use this code, I think your code working.

Comment: Method names are `camelCase` so `blindDates` and `freePaidDates`, and you spelt `blind` wrong... Also, you don't need `user_id` if the model name is `User.php`. Also, Model names are singular, `Users` should be `User`. ALSO `where('id', $user_id)->get()` will return a `Collection` for a single `User`  record. That should be `->where('id', $userId)->first()`, or just `->find($userId)`.